A malicious XSLT could be provided to trigger remote code execution - Sonar Issue

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
final InputStream prunerfileStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("<path to .xsl file which is in src/main/resources>");
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(prunerfileStream));

At line 4, sonar is showing an issue A malicious XSLT could be provided to trigger remote code execution

What is your question?  Sonar is saying this because a malicious XSLT could be provided to trigger remote code execution.  There's nothing else to tell you.

My question is I’m not sure what’s that issue is and how to fix it ??
